# Big O notation For accessing middle element in linked list and binary search?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Article at http://leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/big-oh/bigoh.html says that Big O notation For accessing middle element in linked list is O(N) .should not it be O(N/2) .Assume we have 100 elements in linked list So to access the 50th element it has to traverse right from first node to 50th. So number of operation will be around 50.

One more big notation defined for binary search is log(N). Assume we have 1000 elements. As per log(N) we will be needing the opeartion close to 3. Now lets calculate it manually below will be the pattern

500 th element, 250th, 125,63,32,16,8,4,2  so operation are around 9 which is much larger than 3.

Is there any thing i am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're is missing that any constant multiples don't matter for Big O. So we have O(N) = O(N/2).

About the log part of the question, it is actually log<sub>2</sub>(N) not log<sub>10</sub>(N), so in this case log(1000) is actually 9 (when rounding down). Also, as before, O(log<sub>2</sub>(N)) = O(log<sub>10</sub>(N)), since the two are just constant multiples of each other. Specifically, log<sub>2</sub>(N) = log<sub>10</sub>(N) / log<sub>10</sub>(2)

The last thing to consider is that, if several functions are added together, the function of lower degree doesn't matter with Big O. That's because higher degree functions grow more quickly than functions of lower degree. So we find things like O(N<sup>3</sup> + N) = O(N<sup>3</sup>), and O(e<sup>N</sup> + N<sup>2</sup> + 1) = O(e<sup>N</sup>).

So that's two things to consider: drop multiples, and drop function of low degree.

Answer (score 4):

O(*n*) means "**proportional** to *n*, for all large *n*".<sup>1</sup>

So it doesn't have to be equal to *n*.

#### Edit:

My explanation above was a little unclear as to whether something in O(*n*) is also in O(n<sup>2</sup>). It **is** -- my use of the word "proportional" was poor, and as the others were trying to mention (and as I was misunderstanding originally), "converge" would be a better term.<sup>2</sup>

<sub>1: It *actually* means "proportional to *n* when *n* is large *in the worst-case scenario*", but books usually consider the "average" case, which is more accurately represented by `f(n) ~ n`, where `f` is your function.</sub>

<sub>2: For the more technical people: it should be obvious, but I am ***not*** intending to be mathematically rigorous. Math.SE might be a better choice for asking this question, if you're looking for formal proofs (with ratios, limits, and whatnot).</sub>

Comment: the key is *proportional* - constant factors don't matter

Comment: Actually it doesn't have to be proportional. n+1 is not proportional to `n` (`(n+1)/n` is certainly not constant), but `n+1` is still in O(n).

Comment: @sepp2k: *Actually*, [the ratio is constant for all large n](http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%29%3D%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Cleft%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright%29%3D1.gif). A constant ratio means that they're by definition proportional.

Comment: It does not have to be proportional AND you don't have to measure worse-case scenarios with it. Actually any good algorithms book should at least mention best and worst case performance of an algorithm in Big O notation.

Comment: @Voo: You might find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) enlightning then.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Nothing in there says anything about worst-case. What the table is saying is that e.g. `f(x) = x` is in `O(x^2)` (in addition to being in `O(x)`) and in `Omega(1)` (in addition to being in `Omega(x)`), but only in `Theta(x)`. This is independent of whether f(x) is a function measuring the worst-case performance of an algorithm, the best-case performance or whether it's measuring nothing at all.

Comment: @sepp2k: What does "bounded above" mean to you? Do you consider that to be the average case?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I think "constant for all large n" is a very inaccurate way to say "convergent", but I see what you meant now.

Comment: @sepp2k: Well it's because that's not what I meant. :) They don't have to converge. If the ratio was 5, they would still be proportional, but obviously not converging toward each other.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Bounded above means to me exactly what it says on the right in the table you linked. Note that in all cases you're talking about the same function, so you're talking about the same "case".

Comment: @Mehrdad let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2208/discussion-between-sepp2k-and-mehrdad)

Comment: @Mehrdad So you're saying that all those people measuring average performance of quicksort in Big O (as a famous example where average != worst case performance for an algorithm), just made something up?

Comment: @Voo: Yes, they were hand-waving it. Did your book also mention theta, omega, etc.?

Comment: @Mehrdad "constant for all large n"? Really? Okay, name two large values for n for which the ratio is the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the web page you linked:

> Similarly, constant multipliers are ignored. So a O(4*N) algorithm is
>   equivalent to O(N), which is how it should be written. Ultimately you
>   want to pay attention to these multipliers in determining the
>   performance, but for the first round of analysis using Big-Oh, you
>   simply ignore constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

The Big O notation is a *general* expression of an algorithm's efficiency. You should not construe it as an exact equation for how fast an algorithm is going to be, or how much memory it is going to require, but rather view it as an approximation. The constant multipliers of the function are ignored, so for example you could view your example as O 1/2(N), or O *k*(N), drop the *k* which gives you O(N).

Comment: It's more than a general rule of thumb - it's a mathematical fact that positive multipliers have no effect.

Comment: @Ken - Agreed I could have worded it better, and will.